# Echo PHP Functions into Highcharts Drilldown

Tags: php, highcharts

I have 2 functions that generate "drill down" data for highcharts presentation.

If I run the functions outside of the highcharts javascript and use then manually inset the data generated (as below) into the javascript the chart works fine:

```
$(function () {

Highcharts.theme = {

    chart: {
        height: 480,
        //margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        spacingTop: 30,
        spacingBottom: 20,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 20,
        renderTo: 'this_week_chart',
        type: "line",
        style: {
            //fontFamily: "Open Sans"
            font: '"Open Sans","Source Sans Pro",Helvetica,sans-serif'  
        }
    }
};

Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    series: [{
            type: "column",
            index: 0,
            name: "Total Sales Value (inc. tax)",
            data:
            [
{name: 'Monday', y: null, drilldown: 'Monday'},
{name: 'Tuesday',y: 890, drilldown: 'Tuesday'},
{name: 'Wednesday',y: 1150.5, drilldown: 'Wednesday'},
{name: 'Thursday',y: 1519.5, drilldown: 'Thursday'},
{name: 'Friday', y: null, drilldown: 'Friday'},
{name: 'Saturday', y: null, drilldown: 'Saturday'},
{name: 'Sunday', y: null, drilldown: 'Sunday'}
]
            }],

            drilldown: {
            series:
[
{name: 'Monday',id: 'Monday',data: []},
{name: 'Tuesday',id: 'Tuesday',data: [['17',67],['18',95.5],['19',185],['20',228],['21',209],['22',98],['23',7.5]]},
{name: 'Wednesday',id: 'Wednesday',data: [['17',26],['18',176.5],['19',135.5],['20',248],['21',215],['22',277],['23',72.5]]},
{name: 'Thursday',id: 'Thursday',data: [['0',null],['17',22],['18',111.5],['19',383],['20',211],['21',456.5],['22',157],['23',178.5]]},
{name: 'Friday',id: 'Friday',data: [['0',90],['17',158],['18',203],['19',324.5],['20',509],['21',290.5],['22',5],['23',27.5]]},
{name: 'Saturday',id: 'Saturday',data: [['1',69]]},
{name: 'Sunday',id: 'Sunday',data: []}
]
                    },
    tooltip: {
        borderRadius: 5,
        shared: true
    },
            legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
    plotOptions: {
        arearange: {
            tooltip: {
                followPointer: true
            }
        },
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    fontWeight: "normal",
                    fontSize: "10"
                }
            }
        },
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                format: '${y:,.0f}',
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
        format: '${value:,.0f}'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%a, %b %e'
        }
    }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

If I insert the data as variables however (as follows) the code no longer works:

```
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {

    Highcharts.theme = {

        chart: {
            height: 480,
            //margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            spacingTop: 30,
            spacingBottom: 20,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 20,
            renderTo: 'this_week_chart',
            type: "line",
            style: {
                //fontFamily: "Open Sans"
                font: '"Open Sans","Source Sans Pro",Helvetica,sans-serif'  
            }
        }
    };

    Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        series: [{
                type: "column",
                index: 0,
                name: "Total Sales Value (inc. tax)",
                data:

<?php produce_HC_simple_drill_top($HC_SERIES_BY_DAY, "DAY", "TOTAL_SALES");?>

                }],

                drilldown: {
                series:

<?php produce_HC_simple_drill_bottom_hour($HC_SERIES_BY_DAY,"DAY","TOTAL_SALES", "SALE_HOUR", "TOTAL_SALES", $This_wk_starts, $This_wk_ends); ?>


                        },
        tooltip: {
            borderRadius: 5,
            shared: true
        },
                legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
        plotOptions: {
            arearange: {
                tooltip: {
                    followPointer: true
                }
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: "normal",
                        fontSize: "10"
                    }
                }
            },
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '${y:,.0f}',
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
            format: '${value:,.0f}'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%a, %b %e'
            }
        }
            });
            });
        </script>
```

This makes no sense as I've inserted data generated by PHP into highcharts before without using drilldowns and everything works fine. I can't figure out what is wrong here at all, can anyone help?

Comment: What your PHP returns? I advice you to return your data in PHP as JSON (json_encode function) and then you avoid conflicts in formatting / types etc.

Comment: The php function returns exactly what is shown in the top code block after data: and series: i.e. the exact same output. If i echo the php out and input the resulting data the graph works perfectly, if i inset the php to generate the data in the javascript as shown in the second code block it doesn't. It's amazingly frustrating as inputting php in javascript this way works when not using drill downs for other graphs in higcharts!

Comment: Can you run the console (dev tools in the browser) and check the errors ?  Because probably you inject the string and it causes the problem. Anyway I need to ensure by console. Have you live demo of your chart, anywhere?